# Windows service health/error tracking

Tags: c#, service, monitor

Our clients uses software, which consists of client->gateway->engine. Engine and gateway are implemented as windows service, sometimes on a same machine sometimes not. What we  would like to have is a some type of monitor, which would test if service is running, what are the response times, error tracking etc. So whenever there is a problem with a service, we would have all the data available when, why and what has happened ... so no more remote access, event log. Are there any existing solutions we could incorporate into our software?

What about Microsoft operations manager? Can it be used in our case? I started exploring it, but haven't found any useful information.

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows api which can help to monitor windows service running status.

std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
    const wchar_t* widecstr = widestr.c_str();

```
SC_HANDLE scm = ::OpenSCManager(0, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);

SC_HANDLE service = ::OpenService(scm, L"Audiosrv", SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
if(service == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "NO target service.Fail to monitor Windows Service!" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Start to monitor Windows Service!" << std::endl;
}

SERVICE_NOTIFY serviceNotify = { SERVICE_NOTIFY_STATUS_CHANGE,onServiceNotifyCallback};

while(1)
{
    const DWORD result1 = ::NotifyServiceStatusChange(service,
                                                SERVICE_NOTIFY_RUNNING,
                                                &serviceNotify);

    ::SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE); // Wait for the notification

    const DWORD result2 = ::NotifyServiceStatusChange(service,
                                        SERVICE_NOTIFY_STOPPED,
                                        &serviceNotify);
    ::SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE); // Wait for the notification
}

::CloseServiceHandle(service);
::CloseServiceHandle(scm);
```

}

Here is the whole example project:
https://github.com/gogocanfly/MonitorWindowsService

Hope this will help you.